# I can't deploy my reactjs app it shows app crashed

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I can't deploy my reactjs app in heroku. It shows build successful but app crashed.
And i want to connect my github repository where the code located for auto deployment in heroku.
My app is working fine in localhost, velcel, render, Netlify and others.

[image: This the image tap here to show]

And my package.json file code is

```
{
  "homepage": "https://www.kmnahidulislam.com/",
  "name": "kmnahidulislam",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "colorthief": "^2.3.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.6",
    "gh-pages": "^2.1.1",
    "jest-canvas-mock": "^2.3.1",
    "lottie-react": "^2.4.0",
    "react": "^16.10.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.10.2",
    "react-easy-emoji": "^1.8.1",
    "react-headroom": "^3.0.0",
    "react-reveal": "^1.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.10.2",
    "react-twitter-embed": "3.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.8"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "start": "node fetch.js && react-scripts start",
    "build": "node fetch.js && react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --write \"./**/*.{js,css,json,scss}\"",
    "check-format": "prettier -c \"./**/*.{js,css,json,scss}\""
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.3%",
      "not ie 11",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      ">0.3%",
      "not ie 11",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object": "^7.21.11",
    "dotenv": "^8.6.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1"
  }
}
```

I have tried many ways like adding "Buildpacks"(mars/create-react-app)

My Heroku build logs is :

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 20.x...
       Downloading and installing node 20.11.0...
       Using default npm version: 10.2.4
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       
       added 1558 packages, and audited 1559 packages in 23s
       
       252 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       14 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 6 high, 1 critical)
       
       To address issues that do not require attention, run:
         npm audit fix
       
       To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
         npm audit fix --force
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       npm notice 
       npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.4.0
       npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.4.0>
       npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.4.0` to update!
       npm notice 
       
-----> Build
       Running build
       
       > kmnahidulislam@0.1.0 build
       > node fetch.js && react-scripts build
       
       Fetching profile data for kmnahidulislam
       Fetching Medium blogs data for kmnahidulislam
       statusCode: 200
       saved file to public/profile.json
       statusCode: 200
       saved file to public/blogs.json
       Creating an optimized production build...
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
Browserslist: caniuse-lite is outdated. Please run:
  npx update-browserslist-db@latest
  Why you should do it regularly: https://github.com/browserslist/update-db#readme
       Compiled successfully.
       
       File sizes after gzip:
       
         231.79 kB  build/static/js/main.48fe4e58.js
         5.11 kB    build/static/css/main.ce488826.css
         1.11 kB    build/static/js/64.41aa5367.chunk.js
         870 B      build/static/js/769.7b11bf34.chunk.js
         555 B      build/static/css/64.bba8fa55.chunk.css
         496 B      build/static/css/769.b3cbb36b.chunk.css
       
       The project was built assuming it is hosted at /.
       You can control this with the homepage field in your package.json.
       
       The build folder is ready to be deployed.
       You may serve it with a static server:
       
         npm install -g serve
         serve -s build
       
       Find out more about deployment here:
       
         https://cra.link/deployment
       
       
-----> Caching build
       - npm cache
       
-----> Pruning devDependencies
       
       up to date, audited 1556 packages in 5s
       
       251 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       14 vulnerabilities (7 moderate, 6 high, 1 critical)
       
       To address issues that do not require attention, run:
         npm audit fix
       
       To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
         npm audit fix --force
       
       Run `npm audit` for details.
       npm notice 
       npm notice New minor version of npm available! 10.2.4 -> 10.4.0
       npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.4.0>
       npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.4.0` to update!
       npm notice 
       
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 103.9M
-----> Launching...
       Released v3
       https://nahidul-8c586dc3b95d.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
Build finished
```

And this is the heroku web log:

```
2024-02-04T17:58:28.811247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
2024-02-04T17:58:28.811247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
2024-02-04T17:58:28.811247+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12) {
2024-02-04T17:58:28.811248+00:00 app[web.1]:   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-02-04T17:58:28.811248+00:00 app[web.1]:   requireStack: [ '/app/fetch.js' ]
2024-02-04T17:58:28.811250+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2024-02-04T17:58:28.811250+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2024-02-04T17:58:28.811250+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js v20.11.0
2024-02-04T17:58:28.881657+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-02-04T17:58:28.906884+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

When i visit the website it shows application error

https://nahidul-8c586dc3b95d.herokuapp.com/
Looks this

Comment: Please share the exact error in the Heroku build. This will provide more context into what the solution will be. One possible solution that you can try out is to move `@babel/plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object` to dependencies. Heroku will only install dependencies using yarn install --production. LMK if this fixes the issue.

Comment: I have added the logs in my question.. please see it